# Closed form of $1+\dfrac1{2\pi i}\oint\limits_C F_n(z)\text dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let

$$F_n(z)=\dfrac\pi4\,(z^2-1)\,z^{\large-\frac{n+4}2}\cot{\pi\dfrac{(z-1)^2}{4z}}$$

I'm looking for a closed form of

$$1+\dfrac1{2\pi i}\oint\limits_C F_n(z)\text dz$$

$$C =\left\{\dfrac{52}{16-y^2}+iy,\;y\in(-4,4)\right\}$$

To be honest I've no idea on how to proceed further. I'm not even sure if there even exists a nice closed form. However I got a hint from someone who said that for $n \geqslant 3$, you can relate this to the Riemann zeta function, in short the closed form contains Riemann zeta function.

Your insight would be very helpful, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried thinking about the residues

Comment: uhh not yet but I have tried specific counters and it doesn't seem to give any *nice* closed form

Comment: That's also a big problem, I don't know what appropriate counter is in this case

Comment: For odd $n$, there seems to be a branch point at the origin, so $C$ cannot be a loop that surrounds the origin.

Comment: @Gary I'm most interested in the odd case, could you please elaborate more by answering the question? Thanks.

Comment: @BooleanWick It highly depends on your contour. The answer can pretty much be anything.

Comment: @Gary I have edited the question (which contains the contour), Thanks.

Comment: It would be surprising if there is a better strategy than to substitute $C$ for $z$.

Comment: It would have been useful if you cite https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4114718